Linux bonding mode 0 with 2 differnt swiches
I have a server with 2 physical interfaces and each of them has connected to the SW1 and SW2
from the server I have applied the bonding mode 0 (active-active)
what happens if I applied the configuration as follows below,it will work fine or need some configuration on the switch?
enter image description here
